# How can I query SPARQL endpoints in spring web app

Tags: spring, sparql

I'm trying to build a web application that will allow an user to write a SPARQL query and select an endpoint, and the app will send the query to the selected endpoint. Is there a simple way to do this?

As far as I understand, you can send GET and POST requests to an endpoint. A way to send an endpoint to https://dbpedia.org/ for example, is with the following url: [https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graphuri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3FConcept+where+{[]+a+%3FConcept}+LIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graphuri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+distinct+%3FConcept+where+%7B%5B%5D+a+%3FConcept%7D+LIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0) - where the first part of the url is the selected endpoint and the second part is the entered query. My initial idea was to construct urls this way and than get the results. However, I'm sure there has to be a simpler, more efficient way to do this. I tried to look for solutions online, but I found very little information on this.

Comment: any Java API for SPARQL would the obvious way to go

Comment: @UninformedUser do you have any suggestions?

Comment: no, just use any Java API of your choice. There are plenty well-known with excellent RDF and SPARQL support, e.g. Apache Jena, RDF4J, ...

Comment: @UninformedUser okay, thanks! I was looking into Apache Jena before making this post, but I guess I got confused because it seemed like I wouldn't be able to use it along with spring boot. I did manage to do it though. If you want to, you can post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as solution.